# SQL 00918. 00000 - "column ambiguously defined"

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have the "column ambiguously defined" error in my sql oracle code and I can't figure out why I have the error. I know it means the code can't figure out which of two columns with the same name to use, so I need to use prefixes. But I have prefixes that are all correct. I looked at the other questions on this error message on the site, but can't figure it out.

ORA-00918: kolumn inte entydigt definierad
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 5

```
SELECT KUND.KNR, KUND.FNAMN, KUND.ENAMN
FROM KUND, ORDERRAD, KUNDORDER, KUNDORDER, ARTIKEL, VARUGRUPP
WHERE KUND.KNR = KUNDORDER.KNR
AND KUNDORDER.ORDNR = ORDERRAD.ORDNR
AND ORDERRAD.ARTNR = ARTIKEL.ARTNR
AND ARTIKEL.VGNR = VARUGRUPP.VGNR
AND VARUGRUPP.VGNAMN = 'skäggvård' OR VARUGRUPP.VGNAMN = 'bondgård';
```

Comment: Well, you are still using `KUNDORDER` twice without giving them a unique alias, so, obviously it is ambiguous. Also, are you sure that that `OR` shouldn't be between parentheses?. Lastly, I would start using explicit joins instead of implicit ones

Answer (score 1):

You join the table KUNDORDER twice, so you have to use an alias to help oracle distinguish between them.

But looking at this, most likely you meant to join this table once, and it is a typo.

As a side note: you're using deprecated implicit join notation: it's better to use `FROM tablename JOIN table1 ON (...) JOIN table2 ON (...)`-notation.

Second side note: it's good practice to always use aliases for your joined tables to improve readability, e.g.: `FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON (...)`

Comment: I'd say using ansi join not 'better' but 'doubtful' practise. Especially if looking how much (not many) errors Oracle had & has here.